# Alias inside require function in React

Tags: reactjs, alias

I want to use alias inside require function for dynamically load img src.
There is a list of image items in the component. So it's not possible to import and map all of them manually in src.

Whenever i am trying relative path, it's working.

```
<img src={require('../../assets/images/' + imageurl)} alt={title} />
```

But if i change this line to below one, it's breaking.

```
<img src={`require(@assets/images/${imageurl})`} alt={title} />
```

Note: I already setup my assets alias in the project.

Comment: Set the backticks after require (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
<img src={require(`@assets/images/${imageurl}`)} alt={title} />
```